# Not Able To Identify ASP.Net Image Button in QTP 10

Tags: asp.net, qtp

When i run QTP its not identifying Click Event Of Image Button .Please suggest me work arounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntex.

```
Browser("EHRI Electronic Official_2").Page("EHRI Electronic Official_5").Image("Alt: Accept button: To").Click micNoCoordinate, micNoCoordinate
```